# ERROR 1005: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando crear unas llaves foráneas en una tabla que relaciona a otras 2, pero al momento de referenciar las columnas me lanza el error 1005.

Las tablas a relacionar son `administradores`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rolle`.`ADMINISTRADORES` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `CORREO` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
   `ALIAS` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `ACTIVE` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Y `roles`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rolle`.`roles` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rol_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `display_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `token` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Y se relacionan en la tabla `roles_administradores`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rolle`.`roles_administradores` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `administrador_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `fk_role_id_idx` (`role_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_administrador_id_idx` (`administrador_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_role_id`
   FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
   REFERENCES `rolle`.`roles` (`id`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_administrador_id`
   FOREIGN KEY (`administrador_id`)
   REFERENCES `rolle`.`ADMINISTRADORES` (`id`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Intente borrar las llaves foráneas y volverlas a crear pero no funciono.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, muestra el mensaje de error completo. Gracias.

Comment: Trate de replicar el error y pude crear correctamente las tablas.

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez tiene razón a mi también me corrió bien de todas formas te dejo éste link [MySQL Error 1005](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?71,576294,576318) por si te sirve de algo

Comment: Este es el error : Error 1005: Can't create table `rolle`.`#sql-125c_b7` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") SQL Statement:  ALTER TABLE `rolle`.`roles_administradores`  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_administradores_id`   FOREIGN KEY (`administrador_id`)   REFERENCES `rolle`.`administradores` (`id`)   ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_roles_id`   FOREIGN KEY (`roles_id`)   REFERENCES `rolle`.`roles` (`id`)   ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: Hay algo raro en ese mensaje de error, ¿por qué asume que la tabla se llamaría `#sql-125c_b7`? ¿De dónde sale eso? ¿Estás creando tablas de forma dinámica en alguna parte?

Comment: Es que esa BD no la hice yo, viene de otro programador que parece que la hizo con Wix. Las relaciones ya estaban establecidas, pero como vi que no funcionaban borre las columnas de la tabla relacion y las volvi a hacer

Comment: La cuestión es que el error dice esto: `Error 1005: Can't create table rolle.#sql-125c_b7` entonces yo pregunto, ¿de donde sale ese `CREATE TABLE` que intenta crear una tabla que se llama `#sql-125c_b7`? Y además habla de una consulta `ALTER TABLE`. Debes revisar el contexto en que se están lanzando esos comandos para ver qué es lo que pasa.

Comment: Tampoco lo se, la tabla relación ya existe, no se porque intentaría crear otra

Comment: Por lo que parece el error ocurre en una consulta del tipo `ALTER TABLE`, debes revisar tu código para ver dónde ocurre eso. Lee bien el mensaje de error, dice claramente: `SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE rolle.roles_administradores ADD CONSTRAINT fk_administradores_id ...`

Comment: ¿Estás intentando crear las tablas o quieres actualizarlas?

Comment: Estoy intentando actualizar la tabla roles_administradores. No me dejaba insertar porque me daba error de que los valores no existían en las tablas que quería relacionar, entonces elimine las columnas para volver a hacer las llaves foráneas y ahora cuando ejecuto la query me sale el error 1005

Comment: Ok, si borraste las columnas, debes: 1.- Crea la columna en cada una de tus tablas, 2.- Crea la restricción en la tabla que hará referencia a las columnas recién creadas. Si te marca algún error copia / pega, para que veamos cómo ayudarte